# Xamarin NSNotificatioCenter: How can I get the NSObject being passed?

Tags: c#, ipad, xamarin.ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to post a notification in a view from my app to another one using NSNotificationCenter. So in my destination class I create my observer as follows:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("ChangeLeftSide", delegate {ChangeLeftSide(null);});
```

and I have my method:

```
public void ChangeLeftSide (UIViewController vc)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Change left side is being called");
}
```

Now from another UIViewController I am posting a notification as follows:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("ChangeLeftSide", this);
```

How can I access the view controller that is being passed in my post notification in my destination class? In iOS it is very straight forward but I cannot seem to find my way in monotouch (Xamarin)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, here are the changes that need to be made on the code I posted in the question:

```
public void ChangeLeftSide (NSNotification notification)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Change left side is being called");
    NSObject myObject = notification.Object;
    // here you can do whatever operation you need to do on the object
}
```

And the observer is created:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("ChangeLeftSide", ChangeLeftSide);
```

Now you can cast or type check the NSObject and do anything with it! Done!

Comment: Just funny you spend one year to find answer which is posted below :)

Answer (score 11):

When you `AddObserver`, you want to do it in a slightly different way. Try the following:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("ChangeLeftSide", ChangeLeftSide);
```

and the declaration of your `ChangeLeftSide` method to conform to `Action<NSNotification>` expected by `AddObserver` - giving you the actual `NSNotification` object. :

```
public void ChangeLeftSide(NSNotification notification)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Change left side is being called by " + notification.Object.ToString());
}
```

So when you `PostNotificationName`, you're attaching the UIViewController object to the notification, which can be retrieved in your `NSNotification` via the `Object` property.

Comment: Thank you though :) Definitely you have better wording than mine!